# Why isn't presentModalViewController working?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I coded in button action like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:mainDelegate.window cache:NO];
[mainDelegate.window addSubview:[self.calcentryController view]];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It works fine, but when I use in calcentryController.m in one action:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.weeklyScoreController animated:YES];
```

to go to another viewcontroller, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you aren't using `presentModalViewController` for `calcentryController`?  You can set `modalTransitionStyle` on `calcentryController` to `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` and just use `presentModalViewController:animated` instead of doing manual animations.

The reason this may help is because your code is not calling certain functions like `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, etc., whereas `presentModalViewController:animated` calls all the right functions for presenting new views.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your `weeklyScoreController` is nil.  I'm not sure where you create it, since the code block is not pasted but that's a common mistake I see.

Answer (score 0):

I could be because your code is in **viewDidLoad** instead of **viewDidAppear** as per [presentModalViewController does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059790/presentmodalviewcontroller-does-nothing)

I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deep hierarchy of view controllers' views subviewed into one another, then always try to present with immediately viewcontroller whose view is directly added to the window of ur iphone app.

For e.g. I had 4 levels of view like
window > vc1's view > vc2's view > vc3's view

So when I tried to call [vc3 presentModalViewController] it was not working..
I had to present with vc1 and it worked. I had vc1 referenced as a property to app delegate and hence was able to access easily.

But again, I didn't still find the actual reason, but I can say this worked for me.