# presentModalViewController does nothing

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog

I have a UIViewController (*parent*) that calls `presentModalViewController` with another UIViewController (*child*) on `viewDidLoad`.

If *parent* doesn't have a UINavigationController, then `presentModalViewController` does nothing. If it has a UINavigationController, then `presentModalViewController` shows *child* as expected.

Is this the standard behavior of `presentModalViewController` or is there something else at play here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are presenting it in **viewDidLoad**, try presenting it in **viewDidAppear**.

Comment: That was it. Thank you! Do you know why and what does the UINavigationController have to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Debug your app and look if the child-view isn't nil, if it's nil then it's not standard behavior, otherwise I think it's a standard behavior..

Hope, it helps..

Comment: Not sure I understood. The child view controller is not nil.